# Delete duplicates records between two tables

Tags: sql, duplicates, records

I have two different tables which is users and client. There are many duplicate records. I've tried to remove those duplicates records and saved into one new table but failed. It removes the rows not the records. Are there any query to removes those duplicate records from the two tables?

For example have this rows:

> | car | house | food |
>
> | car | cycle | shoe |
>
> | bus | water | house|

The car and house are the duplicate records. I want to remove them and left the other records in a new table using the GROUP BY.

Comment: "It removes the rows not the records": row and record are the same thing. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: For example  have this rows:

| car | house | food | 
| car | cycle | shoe |
| bus | water | house|

The car and house are the duplicate records. I want to remove them and left the other records in a new table using the GROUP BY

Comment: Why do you have three records per row? Can you change that schema? Because it will make things a **lot** easier if you have one record per row.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion. But I don't know how to group multiple column into single column. Sorry. I'm really new to this SQL and this is my first time using it.

Comment: It may help if you give actual examples of your data. What you currently have listed appears like you have three tables with one row and three columns each and you are saying that any two columns with the same value are duplicates. But normally in SQL we would only say something was a duplicate if it was either duplicates of the key or entire row.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to define what is a duplicate record in your case, is it a record having similar primary key or is it a record having all columns the same. Suppose your record have primary keys:

```
delete from users where id in (select id from client);
```